# Modifying a Compiled Static Library

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ios, xcode

Put on your c++ ninja voodoo gloves.

We purchased a 3rd party library to use in our iOS app. There are 2 versions of that library, so let's call them `bull_frog_noises.a` and `toad_frog_noises.a`.

The company never imagined that someone would want to make *both* frog noises in *a single* app, so each library offers the *same method name*:

```
MAKE_FROG_NOISE();
```

**Is there a way to rebuild or modify these libraries so they can both be used without colliding with each other?**  Here is the ideal state:

```
MAKE_BULL_FROG_NOISE();
MAKE_TOAD_FROG_NOISE();
```

Comment: You can't dynamically load a lib in ios. They're compiled togheter with the app so that you cannot give further functionality to the app without going through apple approval process.

Comment: Thanks Raphael - I don't want people to get too caught up in the dynamic loading idea, so I removed that part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try using a hex editor to manually modify one of those libraries so that every instance of MAKE_FROG_NOISE was replaced with MAKE_TOAD_NOISE. You would have to be extremely careful to make only that one change. You can only replace bytes. Don't insert or delete anything.  And don't change anything else in the file.

Comment: This worked, but it's tricky. You have rename the methods you use AND the private methods it uses if they clash with each other. Anyways, I used `Hex Fiend` to rename one letter of each method & now I can run them side by side.

Answer (score 3):

You can build another static library as a wrapper to those libraries with the method names that you want, and then include the wrappers libraries in the project.

like this:

1 - Create a new static library project named bull_frog_noises_wrapper.a.

2 - Include bull_frog_noises.a as a dependency to this newly created library.

3 - Create methods like this:

```
void MAKE_BULL_FROG_NOISE()
{
    MAKE_FROG_NOISE();
}
```

4 - Do the same for the toad_frog_noises.a, creating methods like:

```
void MAKE_TOAD_FROG_NOISE()
{
    MAKE_FROG_NOISE();
}
```

5 - Add those wrappers in your project and you're done.

Just be careful with the header files you use in the main project so that they do not conflict with the inner libraries.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So would this prevent the internal workings of the library from trampling each other? For example, what if both `MAKE_FROG_NOISE()` methods called a methods like `PREPARE_NOISE()`? Would the correct methods get called?

Comment: This does not solve the problem, as everything still needs to be linked together, and that's where the collision will occur.

Comment: That's why I told to create 2 separated libraries. Each library will be built independent. The toad_frog_noises.a contains a set of headers that will be included only in toad_frog_noises_wrapper.a and the other library will do the same. The link part of the methods occur in the wrapper library, not the project itself.

Comment: For all the methods in the library you purchased, you will have to create a corresponding method in the wrapper library, so where you call PREPARE_NOISE(), you should call PREPARE_TOAD_NOISE() or PREPARE_BULL_NOISE() and those methods would both call PREPARE_NOISE(), but on their own libraries.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work. I created a `Cocoa Touch Static Library` in XCode, imported `bull_frog_noises.a`, wrapped it with `MAKE_BULL_FROG_NOISE()`. Same with the other library, then imported both into my project. One works, but the other fails. I'm afraid that both have calls to private methods like `PREPARE_NOISE()` & creating a wrapper doesn't solve this. Am I missing something?